# data.table fcase default option

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to change from dplyr case_when to data.table fcase function for a question of speed.

My original script in case_when looks like this:

```
df = dplyr::mutate(df, x = dplyr::case_when(
  col1 == "a" & col2 == "b" ~ "m1",
  col1 == "b" & col2 == "a"  ~ "m2",
  TRUE ~ x
))
```

so if none of the conditions are met I just leave the original column value. I am trying to do the same with fcase:

```
df = setDT(df)[, x := fcase(
  col1 == "a" & col2 == "b", "m1",
  col1 == "b" & col2 == "a", "m2",
  default = x
)]
```

however when I try to run this I get the following error:

```
Error in fcase(col1 == "a" & col2 ==  : 
  Length of 'default' must be 1.
```

If I set the default to be any string it works fine. Can anyone tell me how to replicate my case_when code with fcase, if possible? thanks!

Comment: `x` in `default = x` is the whole vector. One solution is to operate rowwise by adding `, by = 1:nrow(df)]`

Comment: Both conditions before default are the same?

Comment: Also an open issue if interested:
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4258#ref-issue-650920677

Answer (score 3):

While it's not as elegant-looking perhaps, I use `rep(TRUE, .N)`.

```r
DT <- data.table(i = 1:6)
DT[, v := fcase(i %in% c(1,3), "A", i %in% c(2), "B",
                rep(TRUE, .N), as.character(i))][]
#        i      v
#    <int> <char>
# 1:     1      A
# 2:     2      B
# 3:     3      A
# 4:     4      4
# 5:     5      5
# 6:     6      6
```

While it's a few more characters, I think `rep(TRUE, .N)` is fairly self-descriptive. If code-golf is primary then you can use something equally "always-true" and guaranteed the same length with `.I > 0`.